# Using FILTER() in DAX

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

What is the best practice in applying filters with CALCULATE() function in Power BI?
Using FILTER() as below:
*Most Expensive Non-Organic = CALCULATE(MAX(dProduct[Amount]), FILTER(dProduct, dProduct[IsOrganic]="N"))*

Or, Using a direct Boolean Expression as below:
*Most Expensive Non-Organic = CALCULATE(MAX(dProduct[Amount]),'dProduct'[IsOrganic]="N")*

Answer (score 1):

When you write a CALCULATE statement, all the filter arguments are table expressions, such as a list of values for one or more columns, or for an entire table. For example, when you write:

```
CALCULATE (
    <expression>,
    table[column] = <value> 
)
```

In reality the filter expression you wrote is transformed in:

```
CALCULATE (
    <expression>,
    FILTER (
        ALL ( table[column] ),
        table[column] = <value> 
    )
)
```

This behavior is identical for all the filter arguments of CALCULATE and CALCULATETABLE.

Your first statement is rather bad.

```
CALCULATE(MAX(dProduct[Amount]), FILTER(dProduct, dProduct[IsOrganic]="N"))
```

correct way for use filter in your example:

```
CALCULATE(MAX(dProduct[Amount]), FILTER(ALL(dProduct[IsOrganic]), dProduct[IsOrganic]="N"))
```

because you provide as filter a full EXPANDED table (you push many column from dProduct and related table).

Read this article:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/